# Show last available options in react-select drill-down menu

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm building a drill-down menu with the react-select package. The goal is to create multiple levels and lead the user to the right option (step-by-step).

Instead of the 'No options page' I want to show the user the last available options.

So if you click on `target 1` -> `sub item 1` -> `sub item nested 1` the menu should close. If the user opens the menu again the user should have the options: `sub item nested 1`  and `sub item nested 2` instead of the `No options` page.

```
function SingleSelect() {
  const [selectOptions, setSelectOptions] = useState({
    isMenuOpen: false,
    closeMenuOnSelect: false,
    renderValue: false,
    options
  });

  function handleOptionClick(e, props) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    const nestedGroup = props.data.sub_items;

    if (nestedGroup) {
      setSelectOptions({
        options: nestedGroup,
        closeMenuOnSelect: false,
        renderValue: false,
        isMenuOpen: true
      });
    }

    if (!nestedGroup) {
      setSelectOptions({
        closeMenuOnSelect: true,
        renderValue: true,
        isMenuOpen: false
      });
    }
  }

  function Option(props) {
    return (
      <div onClick={(e) => handleOptionClick(e, props)}>
        <components.Option {...props} isSelected={false} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Select
      name="options"
      classNamePrefix
      components={{ Option }}
      closeMenuOnSelect={selectOptions.closeMenuOnSelect}
      menuisOpen={selectOptions.isMenuOpen}
      controlShouldRenderValue={selectOptions.renderValue}
      isSearchable={false}
      options={selectOptions.options}
    />
  );
}
```

Example in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-level-react-select-13rtk?file=/index.js

Comment: your code is very interesting and quite creative. There's one important piece missing. How do you think you can model the selected item? Normally that is an object uniquely tracking one item. But in your case, it's a bit complicated. But anyway start by adding `id` to each item then. Because without it you can't identify which is which.